# How do I reset my database state after each unit test without making the whole test a transaction?

Tags: spring, junit, transactions, hsqldb

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JPA 2, JUnit 4.8.1, and HSQL 2.2.7.  I want to run some JUnit tests on my service methods, and after each test, I would like any data written to the in-memory database to be rolled back.  However, I do NOT want the entire test to be treated as a transaction.  For example in this test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class ContractServiceTest 
{
    …

    @Autowired
    private ContractService m_contractService;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateContract()
    {
        // Add the contract
        m_contractService.save(m_contract);
        Assert.assertNotNull(m_contract.getId());
        // Update the activation date by 6 months.
        final Calendar activationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        activationDate.setTime(activationDate.getTime());
        activationDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
        m_contract.setActivationDate(activationDate.getTime());
        m_contractService.save(m_contract);
        final List<Contract> foundContracts = m_contractService.findContractByOppId(m_contract.getOpportunityId());
        Assert.assertEquals(foundContracts.get(0), m_contract);
    }   // testUpdateContract
```

there are three calls to the service, ("m_contractService.save", "m_contractService.save", and "m_contractService.findContractByOppId") and each is treated as a transaction, which I want.  But I don't know how to reset my in-memory database to its original state after each unit test.

Let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Comment: why do you want to avoid the transaction?

Comment: See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854527/run-all-junit-tests-indepentently-in-eclipse-reloading-spring-context-each-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-create database before each test in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617152/how-to-re-create-database-before-each-test-in-spring)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you are using Hibernate, you could use the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to create the database on startup every time.  You would also need to force the spring context to be reloaded after each test.  You can do this with the `@DirtiesContext` annotation.

This might add a bit extra overhead to your tests, so the other solution is to just manually delete the data from each table.

Comment: I added "@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)" at the class level and it did what I need.  There is extra overhead but that doesn't matter in my case.    Rock on

Comment: Yes, I explicitly had to set the classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD). THe default is "After Class", but I wanted a fresh DB ready for reach Unit Test method.

Answer (score 20):

`@DirtiesContext` was no solution for me because the whole application context gets destroyed an must be created after each test -> Took very long.

`@Before` was also not a good solution for me as I have to create `@Before` in each integration test.

So I decided to create an `TestExecutionListener` which recreates the database after each test. (With Liquibase, but it also works with Flyway and normal SQL)

```
public class CleanupDatabaseTestExecutionListener
extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

public final int getOrder() {
    return 2001;
}

private boolean alreadyCleared = false;

@Override
public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    if (!alreadyCleared) {
        cleanupDatabase(testContext);
        alreadyCleared = true;
    } else {
        alreadyCleared = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    cleanupDatabase(testContext);
}

private void cleanupDatabase(TestContext testContext) throws LiquibaseException {
    ApplicationContext app = testContext.getApplicationContext();
    SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = app.getBean(SpringLiquibase.class);
    springLiquibase.setDropFirst(true);
    springLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(); //The database get recreated here
}
}
```

To use the TestExecutionListenere I created a custom test annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = OurderApp.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = 
TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS,
    listeners = {CleanupDatabaseTestExecutionListener.class}
)
public @interface OurderTest {
}
```

Last but not least, I can now create tests and I can be sure that the database is in a clean mode.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@OurderTest
public class ProductSaveServiceIntTest {
 }
```

EDIT: I improved my solution a bit. I had the problem that sometime one test method destroyed my database for all upcoming tests within the test class. So I created the annotation

package com.ourder.e2e.utils;

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ClearContext {
}
```

and added this to the CleanupDatabaseTestExectionListener.

```
@Override
public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    if(testContext.getTestMethod().getAnnotation(ClearContext.class)!=null){
        cleanupDatabase(testContext);
    }
    super.afterTestMethod(testContext);
}
```

with help of these two snippets I am now able to create tests like this:

```
@Test
@ClearContext
public void testWhichDirtiesDatabase() {}
```

Comment: which bean should I get from context if I want to use built-in libraries? 
I have very simple app, and I don't need Liquibase or Flyway.

Comment: Do you want to clear your database tables or recreate the whole sql scheme ?

Comment: Thank you! I need to use **afterTestMethod** instead of **afterTestClass** to clean the database between each test execution

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Transactional` annotation at Junit class level from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

For example:

```
package org.test
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class ArmyTest{

}
```

Comment: The OP said: "without making the whole test a transaction"

Answer (score 2):

I solve the same problem using a random memory database for each test:

```java
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:${random.uuid}"
})
```

Comment: So you have different db contexts in test and real application. That means if something works in tests it still could fail in real application

Answer (score 2):

If you use flyway for migrations, I use the following pattern:

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class JUnit5Class {
    @Autowired
    Flyway flyway;

    @BeforeAll
    public void cleanUp(){
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

`@TestInstance` allows you to make `@BeforeAll` non static and thus you can migrate only once per test class. If you want to reset it for each test remove the class anotation and make change `@BeforeAll` to `@BeforeEach`.

Comment: Is there something same for Liquibase?

Answer (score 2):

As of JUnit 5 you could also create a custom extension and access the data source from the Spring context, like so (using Kotlin):

```
class DatabaseCleanerExtension : AfterEachCallback {
  override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
    val ds = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context).getBean(DataSource::class.java)

    ds.connection.use { connection ->
      connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM my_table").execute()
    }
  }
}
```

You can then register the extension as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(DatabaseCleanerExtension::class)
class SpringJunitExtensionApplicationTests { .. }
```

Now after each test the callback is executed and you can easily annotate any test classes this applies to.

[Here is also a video on settings this up.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfHG9qnSvpQ)

Answer (score 1):

Make a `@Before` method in which you delete all data from database. You are using Hibernate so you can use HQL: `delete from Contract`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue and solved following this

http://www.javafixing.com/2021/10/fixed-how-to-cleanup-h2-db-after-each.html?m=1

basically you can clean the DB after every test method with:

```
@Sql(scripts = "clean_file.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

on `clean_file.sql` you can add all the SQL statements to reset the db