# How do I retain the rollback behaviour on DataJpaTest when annotated by @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-data

Similar to [How to clean database tables after each integration test when using Spring Boot and Liquibase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870345/how-to-clean-database-tables-after-each-integration-test-when-using-spring-boot) I am already using `DataJpaTest`.

What happened was when I am trying to debug a test file it assumes that there is a transaction that gets rolled back, but the test actually needs to run over multiple transactions provided by a separate `Mono.fromCallable` with a `transactionTemplate` that would modify the database and perform locks and wasn't detectable because it was using `Schedulers.immediate()`  during tests.

So what I found was using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` ensures that the transactions are not implicitly created.  But because of it, the database are committed and other tests fail.

I was wondering is there a way to do a "save point" and "restore" during tests rather than using rollback

I've already tried `@DirtiesContext` no luck.